# How to start bluetooth ftp sharing service in android?

Tags: android, service, ftp, bluetooth

I need to handle with this service ( start/ stop ),
But I can't found this class name in document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no BT FTP service in Android. It will have to be implemented similar to OPP and PBAP as applications.